# postgresql 12 streaming replication not working

Tags: postgresql, replication, postgresql-12

I want to set up streaming replication on the Slave.

On the **Primary Server (Server A. Ubuntu 18.04; Postgres 12)** :

1. `sudo nano /etc/postgresql/12/main/postgresql.conf`
2. Set `listen_addresses = '*'`
3. The postgresql.conf settings are :

`wal_level = "logical"`

`archive_mode = "ON"`

`archive_timeout = 3600`

`checkpoint_timeout = 600`

`hot_standby = "ON"`

`max_connections = 700`

`max_wal_sender = 5`

`max_wal_size = 16GB`

`min_wal_size = 2GB`

`max_worker_processes = 30`

`synchronous_commit = "OFF"`

`wal_log_hints = "OFF"`

`wal_recycle = "ON"`

`wal_keep_segments = 4000`

`wal_sync_method = "fdatasync"`

**This Primary Server has already hosted logical replication to another server (Server B. Ubuntu 18.04; Postgres 12)**

On the **Slave Server (Server C. Ubuntu 22.04; Postgres 12)** :

- change the data directory
- set this up as Slave for streaming replication from Server A.

Here is the detail :
After installing postgres (fresh install) I make sure it's running, then I change the data directory :

1. `sudo -u postgres psql`
2. `SHOW data_directory;`. --Output /var/lib/postgresql/12/main
3. Quit psql : `\q`
4. `sudo systemctl stop postgresql`
5. `sudo systemctl status postgresql`
6. `sudo rsync -av /var/lib/postgresql /data/postgresql2`
7. rename the folder : `sudo mv /var/lib/postgresql/12/main /var/lib/postgresql/12/main.bak`
8. Edit the postgresql.conf : `sudo nano /etc/postgresql/12/main/postgresql.conf`
9. Set to new location : `data_directory = '/data/postgresql2/postgresql/12/main'`
10. Start the db again : `sudo systemctl start postgresql`

The result is good. Postgres is running well on Server C. When I do `SHOW data_directory;` it gives out :  `/data/postgresql2/postgresql/12/main`

Then I setup **streaming replication** on Server C :

1. stop the service on the slave : `systemctl stop postgresql@12-main.service`
2. `su - postgres` then `cp -R /data/postgresql2/postgresql/12/main /data/postgresql2/postgresql/12/data_original`
3. Remove the old directory :

   `rm -rf /data/postgresql2/postgresql/12/main/*`
4. Then do base backup :

   `pg_basebackup -h 10.100.9.40 -p 5432 -U rep_user -D  /data/postgresql2/postgresql/12/main -Fp -Xs -R -P -v`
5. Restart : `systemctl start postgresql@12-main.service`

--gives out error :

```
*`Job for postgresql@12-main.service failed because the service did not take the steps required by its unit configuration.
See "systemctl status postgresql@12-main.service" and "journalctl -xeu postgresql@12-main.service" for details`*
```

6. Then I start using another way : `sudo -i -u postgres`
   `/usr/lib/postgresql/12/bin/pg_ctl start -D /data/postgresql2/postgresql/12/main`

It gives out error :

*`waiting for server to start....postgres: could not access the server configuration file  "/data/postgresql2/postgresql/12/main/postgresql.conf": No such file or directory`*

Please help. What might cause this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to set up replication on the standby. At the very minimum, you have to set `restore_command` in `postgresql.conf` and create `standby.signal`.

The whole dance with renaming directories and running `rsync` is unnecessary, all that is needed is `pg_basebackup`.

Comment: ok.thanks @LaurenzAlbe . Yes, agreed, the renaming directories and `rsync` are not part of the replication process. I just have to do it because I have to move the directory due to the tiny size of the original drive.